# Can't display my JFrame and table at the same time

Tags: java, forms, intellij-idea, jframe

So I've created a gui in the form on intellij and when I take out the code having to do with the table it comes out exactly how I want it, but when I put the code in all I get is the table itself. I was having trouble adding columns using the gui form itself and found a tutorial on showing how to add columns and such using the code. How would I be able to add rows to the table and/or have the table on the form

```
public class App extends JFrame{
    private JButton createRecordButton;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel east;
    private JPanel west;
    private JPanel south;
    private JButton deleteRecordButton;
    private JButton viewStatisticsButton;
    private JButton downloadDataButton;
    public JTable TestDB;



    public App() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("App");
        frame.setContentPane(new App().panel1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        table gui=new table();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(600,200);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("The DataBase Table");




    }
}
```

Comment: Please check [JTableSample.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8luyi37rcbcdm65/JTableSample.zip).

Comment: @CrazyCoder it doesn't answer the question in the fact it's only displaying the table itself

Comment: Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe what you want to achieve (a mockup image or a screenshot would be nice).

Comment: Here's a link to what I want it to look like. On the left is where I want the table https://imgur.com/bWlhloa @CrazyCoder

Comment: I've updated the sample, please [download it again](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8luyi37rcbcdm65/JTableSample.zip). Is that what you need? You are probably mixing up `JFrame` and `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating an exception on line: frame.setContentPane(new App().panel1);
Note that you create the App object but the panel1 object is still null.
Use this code and you will see that both JFrames will appear:

```
public class App extends JFrame{
private JButton createRecordButton;
private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel east;
private JPanel west;
private JPanel south;
private JButton deleteRecordButton;
private JButton viewStatisticsButton;
private JButton downloadDataButton;
public JTable TestDB;



public App() {
    panel1 = new JPanel();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("App");
    frame.setContentPane(new App().panel1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JFrame gui=new JFrame();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(600,200);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("The DataBase Table");




}
```

}

Comment: Are you familiar with how IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer works? It generates the code to perform the initialization of the components and instruments bytecode with it so that user doesn't need to initialize the components bound do UI forum.

Comment: When I do that the other table with the buttons comes up empty. Is there any way they could be on the same gui?

Comment: Hi @Nick. The table is empty because you didn't insert data. Your program opens two windows because you create two JFrames. Please look how to use java swing and good luck https://www.javatpoint.com/java-swing